# How to get the number of days between LocalDateTime instances, ignoring the time

Tags: java, localdatetime

I almost caused an online bug by using LocalDateTime until,For example:

```
@Test
public void test(){

    DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-08-09 11:00:00", df);

    LocalDateTime endTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-08-11 10:00:00", df);

    System.out.println(startTime.until(endTime, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
}
```

I initially thought he should return 2 day , but it turned out to be 1 day !

Then I looked at the corresponding source code, and I now seem to understand it: if more than one day, less than two days, it will only return  one day.

I want to ask if there is a tool available in Java or Spring that meets my needs.

I want it to go back to 2 days, which fits people's intuition.

Of course, I could wrap a utility class to do this, but I wonder if there is an implementation available in Java?

My business scenario looks like this: if it is > 3 days, something will be done.

For example:

if the start time is **2022-08-11 10:00:00**, the operation will be performed after **2022-08-14 10:00:00**.

However, when I call the API at **2022-08-14 11:00:00**, I return 3, which does not meet the condition > 3.

Therefore, The task is still not executed, causing the bug.

Comment: "I want it to go back to 2 days, which fits people's intuition." That definitely wouldn't fit *my* intuition. Your end is less than two days later than your start, so I think it would be very odd to return two... The documentation seems fairly clear on this, too: "The calculation returns a whole number, representing the number of complete units between the two date-times. For example, the amount in months between 2012-06-15T00:00 and 2012-08-14T23:59 will only be one month as it is one minute short of two months."

Comment: Your starting day time is 11.00:00 and end date time is 10:00:00. Which is 1 hour less than 24 hours. That is why it is giving you 1 day.

Comment: Depending on what you are really after, `LocalDate` (no `Time`) might fit your needs.

Comment: not sure when you need to return 2 days or 1 days but you 
can use ChronoUnit.HOURS instead of Day and divide it by 24.0 and round the result

Comment: `LocalDateTime.now(yourDesiredTimeZoneId).isAfter(startTime.plusDays(3))`?

Answer (score 3):

> My business scenario looks something like this: If the current time is within three days of a certain time, something will be done.

That sounds a lot like you are working with *dates* rather than *dates + times*. Therefore, you should use a `LocalDate` instead.

You can convert both `startTime` and `endTime` to `LocalDate` like this:

```
System.out.println(
    startTime.toLocalDate().until(endTime.toLocalDate(), ChronoUnit.DAYS)
);
```

Or better, just parse the strings as `LocalDate`s in the first place, not `LocalDateTime`.

```
var startTime = LocalDate.parse("2022-08-09 11:00:00", df);

var endTime = LocalDate.parse("2022-08-11 10:00:00", df);

System.out.println(startTime.until(endTime, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set `startTime` at the same hour, minutes and seconds of `endTime` (or viceversa). Then compare them and it will give you 2 days.